# UICollectionView is calling `sizeForItem` for all cells ahead of time?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm making an infinitely scrolling ticker and I'm running into this issue where the `UICollectionView` will call `sizeForItem` for *every* cell before loading. I don't understand why it would do this as only a certain number are being displayed at a given time

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        print("sizeForItem\(Date())")
        let height = collectionView.frame.height
        guard tickerItems.count > 0 else {
            return CGSize(width: 500, height: 250)
        }

        let tickerCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? TickerCell ?? TickerCell()
        let tickerItem = tickerItems[indexPath.row % tickerItems.count]
        let width = tickerCell.width(for: tickerItem)
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
```

Some things that occurred to me:
Maybe I'm returning really small widths? Nope, I checked they are normal.
Is prefetching enabled? Nope, I disable it.

```
 public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tickerItems.count > 0 ? 100000 : 0

    }
```

Even if I disable the timer which controls the auto-scrolling, I still have the same issue. **The collectionView is calculating the sizes for every single index even if that index isn't being displayed for a long time.** i.e. It will literally calculate the sizes 100,000 indexes before finally unblocking the UI loading the collectionView.

Comment: You don't need 100000 cells for an infinite ticker either. You only need twice the width of the screen.  It is probably easier to use a scrollview directly

Answer (score 0):

The collection view needs to know how big it will be so it needs to get the size of all cells. A collection view is a scroll view. It needs to know its content size and it can only determine that by asking you how big all of its cells are.